# How do I create a compressed buildroot system image that expands to fill the available storage of the media it is flashed to?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded, buildroot

I need to make a Buildroot system for various x86_64 EFI systems with varying storage sizes, but unfortunately, the pc_x86_64_efi config creates an img file with a fixed partition size, not one that expands to the full size of the media it is flashed to. If I want it to fill the various drives, I need to manually specify the size of the drive in the filesystem config, and then recompile, which is a major pain, and ends up making a massive 128GB+ image file. I tried causing it to resize from within the running system using resize2fs, but that did not work. Ideally I would like it to either expand to the full size of the drive when it is flashed, or to have it resize when it first boots. Is this possible, or is it outside the limits of Buildroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 'parted' and 'resize2fs' built you can resize the partition, resize the filesystem then reboot in a script.

For example here's a system I'm building with a 500MB image flashed onto a 16GB SD Card:

```
# parted -s /dev/mmcblk0 u s p
Model: SD SL16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31116288s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      1s      65536s    65536s    primary  fat16        boot, lba
 2      65537s  3111628s  3046092s  primary  ext4
```

The 2nd line gives the total size of the disk, and assuming the partition you need to resize is the last partition you can issue the following commands to expand it to the max:

```
# parted -s /dev/mmcblk0 u s resizepart 2 31116287
# resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0
# reboot
```

Comment: I ended up writing a shell script along those lines, thanks! Here's what I have, although this does take a long time to run: `printf "fix\n" | parted ---pretend-input-tty /dev/sda print
parted ---pretend-input-tty /dev/sda resizepart 2 100%
resize2fs /dev/sda1`